# Can't set or get NGXS state with Angular 8 NativeScript app

Tags: angular, nativescript, ngxs

Worked with Angular for a while, so while working through a NativeScript tutorial I decided to try out the NGXS data store for the first time. I've tried ~5 different NGXS written tutorials (starting with the NS docs) but can't get state to update despite no errors thrown by Android Studio or NS.

NGXS 3.5 | Angular 8.0 | NativeScript 5.4

final state of attempt => https://github.com/argarner/ns-ng-course/commits/ngxs-failed-integration

// app.module.ts

```
import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';
import { ChallengeState } from './shared/challenge.state';

...
imports: [
    ...
    NgxsModule.forRoot([ChallengeState])
],
```

// ./shared/challenge.state.ts

```
import { State, Action, StateContext, Selector } from '@ngxs/store';

export class SetChallengeAction {
    static readonly type = '[Challenge Edit Component] Set Challenge';
    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

export interface ChallengeStateModel {
    currentChallenge: string;
}

@State<ChallengeStateModel>({
    name: 'challenge',
    defaults: {
        currentChallenge: 'kjsdjfkljslkfsd'
    }
})
export class ChallengeState {
    @Selector()
    static getChallenge(state: ChallengeStateModel) {
        return state.currentChallenge;
    }

    @Action(SetChallengeAction)
    setChallenge(
        { patchState }: StateContext<ChallengeStateModel>,
        { payload }: SetChallengeAction
    ) {
        patchState({ currentChallenge: payload });
    }
}
```

// current-challenge.component.ts

```
import { Select, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { ChallengeState } from '~/app/shared/challenge.state';

export class CurrentChallengeComponent {
    currentChallenge: Observable<string>;
    constructor(private store: Store) {
        this.currentChallenge = this.store.select(
            state => state.challenge.currentChallenge
        );
    }
}
```

// current-challenge.component.html

```
<Label class="title" [text]="currentChallenge | json"></Label>
```

If I don't use the json pipe the Label text displays as `[object object]`

With the json pipe the Label text is `{ "_isScalar": false }`

This never changes no matter how I get, set or access NGXS State.

What am I missing? Is there a fundamental incompatibility with NGXS and NS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Store.prorotype.select` returns an `Observable`, thus you have to pipe with an `async` pipe first:

```html
<Label class="title" [text]="currentChallenge | async"></Label>
```

Also you don't need to map the state using the callback, you've already created a memoized selector, everything you have to do is:

```js
currentChallenge = this.store.select(ChallengeState.getChallenge);
```